# Reduction clause in OpenMP when parallel and for belong to two different statements

Tags: openmp

I am confused with the behavior of the `reduction` clause because when
I compile

```
int main() {

  //default(none) shared(suma)
  int suma = 0;
  #pragma parallel omp default(shared) num_threads(2)
  {
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:suma)
    for (int n = 0; n<20; n++ ) { 
      for ( int j = 0; j < 30; j++ ) { 
        suma += 1;
      }   
    }   
  }
  printf("suma = %d\n", suma);
  assert( suma == 20*30);

  return 0;
}
```

the compiler says that I have to declare `suma` as shared whereas I explicitly specified it to be shared.

```
reduction.cpp:28:33: error: reduction variable must be shared
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:suma)
                            ^
```

What drives me mad is that when I write code that is supposedly incorrect (over-parallelized) it works

```
int main() {

  //default(none) shared(suma)
  int suma = 0;
  #pragma parallel omp default(shared) num_threads(2)
  {
    #pragma parallel omp for reduction(+:suma)
    for (int n = 0; n<20; n++ ) { 
      for ( int j = 0; j < 30; j++ ) { 
        suma += 1;
      }   
    }   
  }
  printf("suma = %d\n", suma);
  assert( suma == 20*30);

  return 0;
}
```

At this point I don't know if I am missing something or if there is a bug in the compiler. Anyway, I am compiling with `clang++ -fopenmp reduction.cpp`

```
clang version 7.0.0 (https://git.llvm.org/git/clang.git/ bb7269ae797f282e27e47eb4ebedfa6abe826e9e) (https://git.llvm.org/git/llvm.git/ 37d8f03a3676034f21f0a652359ec4ace8d0521f)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: You've got the order of pragma keywords wrong: it should be `#pragma omp parallel`, not `#pragma parallel omp`

Comment: Hint: Enable compiler warnings (`-Wall`) and listen to them!

Comment: Did you fix your faulty pragmas as suggested?

Comment: Yes, and it worked. It was my fault, when I tried to find the simplest case of failure of my program I carelessly wrote the pragmas. Nonetheless, in my humble opinion, that should be reported as an error, not a warning.